# Analytical formulation of a Hierarhical Bayes problem

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

In the free online book [Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers), the last figure shows the estimation of the expected value of $\lambda$ for any given day:

[image: ente for image description here]

It looks like the author is calculating the expected value of the posterior for $\lambda$ for a given day. To do so, the author re-uses the MCMC samples from the full estimation of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

But how does the **posterior of $\lambda$ for a given day** relate to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? And why can one **re-use** the samples from the full MCMC calculation?

In case it matters, below is the Python code in question that calculates the red line in the graph above.

```
figsize(12.5, 5)
# tau_samples, lambda_1_samples, lambda_2_samples contain
# N samples from the corresponding posterior distribution
N = tau_samples.shape[0]
expected_texts_per_day = np.zeros(n_count_data)
for day in range(0, n_count_data):
    # ix is a bool index of all tau samples corresponding to
    # the switchpoint occurring prior to value of 'day'
    ix = day < tau_samples
    # Each posterior sample corresponds to a value for tau.
    # for each day, that value of tau indicates whether we're "before"
    # (in the lambda1 "regime") or
    #  "after" (in the lambda2 "regime") the switchpoint.
    # by taking the posterior sample of lambda1/2 accordingly, we can average
    # over all samples to get an expected value for lambda on that day.
    # As explained, the "message count" random variable is Poisson distributed,
    # and therefore lambda (the poisson parameter) is the expected value of
    # "message count".
    expected_texts_per_day[day] = (lambda_1_samples[ix].sum()
                                   + lambda_2_samples[~ix].sum()) / N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of notation, let $\mu_t$ be expected number of text messages per day. Then 
$$\mu_t = f_t(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
\lambda_1 & t<\tau \\
\lambda_2 & t\ge \tau
\end{array} \right.$$
which is a deterministic function of the parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $\tau$. The posterior expectation is 
$$E[\mu_t|y] = E[f_t(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau)|y] = \int \int \int f_t(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau) p(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau|y) d\lambda_1 d\lambda_2 d\tau$$
where $p(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau|y)$ is the posterior distribution of our parameters. We can approximate this expectation using samples $(\lambda_1^{(j)},\lambda_2^{(j)},\tau^{(j)}) \sim p(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\tau|y)$ from the posterior via 
$$E[\mu_t|y] \approx \frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J f\left(\lambda_1^{(j)},\lambda_2^{(j)},\tau^{(j)}\right).$$
Generally, we can approximate any deterministic function of the parameters using this technique.